# System.Drawing,Common - Parameter is not Valid when saving generated QR Code

Tags: c#, png, system.drawing

I'm trying to create a function that generates a qr code based on the url parameters and display it on screen.
Error details:

> System.ArgumentException
> HResult=0x80070057
> Message=Parameter is not valid.
> Source=System.Drawing.Common
> StackTrace:
> at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
> at FunctionAppSample.QRCodeGeneratorFunction.Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.MethodInvokerWithReturnValue'2.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker'2.d__10.MoveNext()

I've been getting this error that says 'Parameter is not Valid' on this code snippet.

```
var qrCodeImage = GenerateQRCode(parameterText);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    qrCodeImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/png")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "QRCode.png"
    };

    return result;
}

private static Bitmap GenerateQRCode(string qrText)
{
    QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
    QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(qrText, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
    QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
    using (Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
    {
        return qrCodeImage;
    }
}
```

I have tried manually adding a new MemoryStream, and saving the image in my local device in the parameters. I have no idea on what parameter is invalid in this line.

Comment: The `GenerateQRCode` method returns a disposed image to the caller because the `using` statement disposes `qrCodeImage` at the end of the method. Just return `qrCode.GetGraphic(20)` and the caller must dispose of it. Create it in the caller with `using`. i.e. `using (var qrCodeImage = GenerateQRCode(parameterText)) { ... }`